# file system not supported error while adding a file to sql filegroup with filestream

Tags: sql-server-2008, groups, filestream

i am a beginner with sql server 2008, i was trying to add a file to a filegroup so that i an create a table which uses filestream, but i keep getting an errors.

here is the code that i am trying:

ALTER DATABASE dbtry1

ADD FILEGROUP dbtry1_fg_filestream CONTAINS FILESTREAM

GO

ALTER DATABASE dbtry1

ADD FILE

(

NAME= 'dbtry1_filestream',

FILENAME = 'E:\Projects\fs.ndf'

)

TO FILEGROUP dbtry1_fg_filestream

GO

the errors:

Msg 5134, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

The path that is specified by 'E:\Projects\fs.ndf' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files because it is not on a supported file system.

Msg 5009, Level 16, State 14, Line 1

One or more files listed in the statement could not be found or could not be initialized.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

FILESTREAMs require NTFS. Is your e: drive FAT?

See http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb933993 and note the second paragraph (emphasis added):

> FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an ***NTFS*** file system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object

Comment: yes, my E: drive is FAT32!
can i not use FAT32 drives at all?

Comment: See the first sentence of my reply.